# ReactJS Axios.delete().then() no se ejecuta

Tags: api, reactjs, axios, postman

Estoy intentando hacer una peticion delete a una api local en Laravel. La api funciona bien al probarla con postman. Tengo el mismo código pero utilizando peticiones get y post y funcionan a la perfeccion.

Este es el codigo de la función en cuestion.

```
onDelete(id){

    axios.delete('http://localhost:8000/api/category/'+id)
    .then(res => {
        //nada de lo que haya aqui se ejecuta
        if(res.status == 200 || res.status == 410){

            toast('¡Eliminado!', {
                type: toast.TYPE.SUCCESS
            });

            document.getElementById('inputName').value = '';

        }else{
            toast('Lo sentimos, algo salió mal. Intente mas tarde.', {
                type: toast.TYPE.ERROR
            });
        }
    });
}
```

La eliminacion del recurso si se realiza, por lo que el delete() se ejecuta corractamente. El problema esta en que no se ejecuta el then().

Comment: te dá algún error, o solo no se ejecuta?, otra cosa hiciste `console.log(res)` que tipo de respuesta te trae?. además por lo que veo , no te veo un catch ahí para capturar los errores.

Comment: Ningun error. Cualquier cosa que haga dentro del then no se ejecuta, por lo tano un console.log() tampoco.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCION: Resulta que axios analiza automaicamente el codigo de error obtenido al ejecutar la peticion. Los codigos exitosos (200, 201, etc) activan el then y los codigos de fallo(404, 410, etc) activan el catch.

En mi caso, al eliminar un registro la api devuelve el codigo 410 (el recurso existia pero ya no) como codigo de confirmacion de la eliminacion. Es decir mi caso de exito se encontraria en el catch y no en el then.